# What is the difference between zend-framework and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-studio

I know that both ZF and CI are coded in Object Oriented MVC pattern. I know how to use PHP OOP programming. I've just downloaded ZF and CI but have no idea of it.

1. Which one is easier to use?
2. Is the way of coding similar in both framework?
3. Should we use Zend Studio for CI?

I don't know the difference between ZF and CI. Please give me the idea so that I can select which one to start first or use both together.

Comment: _Which one is easier to use_ - that's a subjective question. Try both, and see which you prefer. (You may end up using a structured framework like CI and then adding components from Zend, but one step at a time).

Comment: There are countless comparisons of the frameworks out on the web. Please consult these.

Comment: There are also countless SO questions about this.

Comment: I spent three days trying to get ZF working and had CI installed in 10 minutes.  CI is supposed to have the best documentation.  I don't know if it was "best", but can say their documentation was very easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Which is easier to use?**

   There is no consistant way to answer this question. It's subjective. Some programmers who prefer the structure of ZEND will argue that it is easier because it is architected in a way that makes it easy. Others will argue that using CI is easier because it is less bloated and there is a lot less to learn. If you're not experienced in frameworks I suggest CI.
2. **Is the way of coding similar in both framework?**

   No, The frameworks are nothing like each other. Apples to Oranges. Zend is a extremely abstract framework in comparison and includes concepts such as routing, namespacing and object factories to name a few.
3. **Should we use Zend Studio for CI?**

   Completely up to you. I use Emacs, others use Netbeans or Eclipse or Dreamweaver. Google search the benefits of other IDEs and see if Zend Studio sticks.